# How to return correctly a NSMutableString from a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, nsmutablestring

I'm looking for a good way to return a string constructed by a NSMutableString avoiding leaking :

eg:

```
+(NSString *)myMethod{



 NSMutableString *numberToReturn = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 [numberToReturn appendString:@"lorem ipsum"];


 return numberToReturn;
}
```

The leak instrument said I had leak with this variable.

I tried autorelease but it crashes
I tried to return a copy or copying the mutablestring into a nsstring but leak still present.

Any idea or trick?
I'have a to call this method each time the user type a value into the textfield, so the application crashes due to bad memory management...

thank you

Answer (score 12):

You should use `-autorelease`. Your method should be written as:

```
+ (NSString*)myMethod {
    NSMutableString *stringToReturn = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [stringToReturn appendString:@"lorem ipsum"];

   return [stringToReturn autorelease];
}
```

If there is a crash, the fault is elsewhere.

Of course, you can make use of factory methods that return an already-autoreleased instance, rewritting your method as

```
+ (NSString*)myMethod {
  NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
  [result appendString:@"lorem ipsum"];

  return result;
}
```

or better yet for your example,

```
+ (NSString*)myMethod {
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"lorem ipsum"];
    //...do something with result;
    return result;
}
```

Obviously if you method's only purpose is just to return a new string with a string, you can avoid the whole method all together and use `[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"lorem ipsum"]` if you really need a mutable string.

Comment: Just to clarify the "If there is a crash, the fault is elsewhere."  You shouuld make sure you don't release an autoreleased object elsewhere. The string returned from this method will be released when the autoreleasepool is released (normally every cycle of the run loop). If you release it somewhere and then the autorelease pool tries to release it too, your program will crash. EITHER autorelease OR release for each time an object is retained.

Answer (score 4):

You should autorelease the string before returning it. That's what [the memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) say to do. If your app then crashes, that's evidence of a bug somewhere else in your code.