# app is crashing when i try to release nsmutablestring please help on this

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsmutablestring

intialised `NSMutableString` as below:

```
 -(NSString*)filterIt:(NSString*)source
{
    temp1= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"rlm;" withString:@""]];
    //NSString *m_temp;
    temp1 = [temp1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@""];
    temp1 = [temp1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#x" withString:@"&#x"];
    NSRange range = [temp1 rangeOfString:@"&#x"];
    NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(range.location, 8);
    if (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString* temp2 = [temp1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range1 withString:@""];
        //[temp1 setString:temp2];
        temp1 = temp2;
        range = [temp1 rangeOfString:@"&#x"];
        while (range.location < [temp1 length]) {
            range1 = NSMakeRange(range.location, 8);
            temp2 = [temp1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range1 withString:@""];
            //[temp1 setString:temp2];
            temp1 = temp2;
            range = [temp1 rangeOfString:@"&#x"];
        }
    }
    //m_temp = [temp1 mutableCopy];
//  [temp1 release];
    return temp1;
}
```

if i try to release this string in dealloc method and try to run the app my app is crashing.

please give me some suggestions that how can i release this **temp1**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: at where are you trying to release it ? in the same function ? or out side the function ?

Comment: Are you somewhere overwriting `temp1` again ? In short, as you can see by the comments: you need to provide *way* more information and context.

Comment: @Chakradhar - the crash occurs because you send an extra `release` message after your object as been deallocated.

Comment: ...and I was about to flag this question as vulgar until I read it again carefully.

Comment: i worte this line in one function and i am returning temp1 value, rying to release this in dealloc method

Comment: @Druv: did you get mu question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return your Mutable string as auto release

OR

refer [this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835629/how-to-return-correctly-a-nsmutablestring-from-a-method)

Comment: yes..tried like that only ...not working...i m trying to post my code but not accepting in this text box

Comment: provided the code...in that i changed nsmutablestring to nsstring

Comment: temp1= [source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"rlm;" withString:@""]; if "source" is nsstring

Comment: @Chakradhar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1567/discussion-between-maulik-and-chakradhar)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are making this call inside a method. Based on the code you provided, make sure the code fragment is actually:

`temp1= [[NSMutableString alloc]
           initWithString:[source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"rlm;"  withString:@""]];`

I'm assuming you are calling stringByReplacingOcurrenceOfString:withString: to sources.

Having said that, you claim that the program crashes when reaching 'dealloc'.. this would mean that temp1 is declared as an instance variable in your code... If that is the case, the correct code should be (assuming temp1 is a declared property with retain attribute set):

`self.temp1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]
           initWithString:[source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"rlm;"  withString:@""]];`

If temp1 is not an instance variable nor a property, you might want to indicate inside the method that temp1 is a NSMutableString and return the object autoreleased.

Comment: You just added more code.. try to display it better. It is unreadable.

Comment: It seems that temp1 is an instance variable. Is it a property with the retain attribute set, too?